# Kivy: Making a persistent notification with buttons

Tags: android, python, user-interface, kivy

I'd like to make an Android app, and I prefer to not have to step out of my comfort zone which is Python. I heard that the Kivy package can make Android apps, but I heard that it likely doesn't have the full Android UI functionality that you could access using Java.

My desired app should have a persistent notification, that's visible even when the screen is locked, and which has 4 buttons on it, which should respond to pressing and holding them. **Is that possible with Kivy?** Can anyone point me to the functions or classes that I'd use to make this notification and buttons?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know answer for this question, but I have few thoughts you may find useful.

When it comes to calling platform specific API in Kivy it's almost always being done with [calling native Java function from Python](http://pyjnius.readthedocs.io/en/latest/android.html) using `pyjnius` module. There're not much places where it's actually happens in Kivy: in python-for-android `android` recipe ([source](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/tree/master/pythonforandroid/recipes/android/src/android)) that provides [some](https://github.com/kivy/python-for-android/blob/master/doc/source/old_toolchain/android.rst) basic stuff and `plyer` [project](https://github.com/kivy/plyer) that tries to provide high-level cross-platfrom API to some platform functionalities.

I guess that's all you have now and I didn't see there something that does what you want. I guess only way left is:

1. Investigate Android API
2. Write Java solution
3. Use it from Kivy/Python by `pyjnius`

But note that if most part of your app is Android API related you probably wouldn't need Kivy at all: you can just avoid third step in this case.